# Symfony2 with Dynamic Elements

Tags: symfony

Is there something like Bundle in Symfony2 that I can do this? I searched a lot.

http://www.thatsquality.com/examples/todo/advanced

**Update**

I do have table with id and item. I loaded it from the db. All items are shown in a text field, so I can edit them and at the bottom there is an empty text field. If I hit enter or submit all changes are saved to database. The page is going to be reloaded and all items are going to be listed as well with an extra empty bottom text field.

Answer (score 2):

There's no bundle that allows you to do this but it's not too hard to develop.

So, you can use Event Subscribers to get the same behavior, Fields will then be generated according to you table content. As long as you click on save, your form will be then generated again, taking into account the last added elements, your Subscriber should also append an extra field to allow adding new elements.